# Counterexample for $\int_a^b f < \int_a^b g \Rightarrow f(x)≤g(x), \forall x \in [a,b]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

On [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities), I found out that if $f,g$ are any two Riemann integrable functions then $$f(x)< g(x)\, , \ \forall x \in[a,b] \implies \int_a^b f < \int_a^b g$$

I was wondering if the other way around was true? So (luckily) I made a function that had less area under the curve when above the $X$ axis and the same (signed) area when when below the $X$ axis.

Take $$f(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}\sin x & , x \in [0,π] \\ \\ \sin x & , x \in (π,2π]\end{cases}$$ and $g(x) = \sin x , \ x\in [0,2π]$ so $$\int_0^{2π} f < \int_0^{2π} g  \nRightarrow f(x)<g(x), \forall x \in [0,2π]$$

---

Now, I want a counterexample to $$\int_a^b f < \int_a^b g  \Rightarrow f(x)≤g(x), \forall x \in [a,b]$$

Comment: You can change a Riemann integrable function arbitrarily at a finite number of points without changing the integral, so you can easily construct such counterexamples.

Comment: @geetha290krm wait what? That's the point of that counterexample... Did you miss $\nRightarrow$?

Comment: $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2+\frac17$ on $[0,1].$

Comment: $f(x)=x$ $g(x) = -x + \epsilon$, on [-1, 1]

Comment: if you require $f$ and $g$ to be continuous then the conditions are equivalent

Comment: @CSquared No! There are plenty of counterexamples already given here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't require anything about your functions other than Riemann integrability, that's trivial.   Let $f(x)=1$ on $(0,1]$  AND $f(0)=5$.   Then the integral is $1$.  Let $g(x)=100000x$.   That integrates to an area of $50000$ but $f(0)>g(0)$

Comment: $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = 1$ not $0$. And you don't need the discontinuity in $f$ for this example to work.

Comment: Man, I just wanna cry. I spent half an hour coming up with that counterexample and I was really proud about it too... when there was something this obvious...

Comment: *grin* No worries.  I spent a morning being confused about the rational indicator function having a fourier transform of 0...I forgot that in $L^2$ spaces, functions are only identified up to sets of measure 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Another counterexample (with continuous functions).

$f(x)=1\quad$ for any $\;x\in[0,3]\;,$

$g(x)=x\quad$ for any $\;x\in[0,3]\;.$

It results that

$\displaystyle\int_0^3 f(x)\,dx=3<\frac92=\int_0^3 g(x)\,dx$

but $\;f(x)>g(x)\;\;$ for any $\;x\in[0,1[\;.$

Comment: this isn’t a counterexample in my opinion.  the bounds of integration should be $0$ to $1$, not $0$ to $3$

Comment: @CSquared, it is a counterexample for $$\int_a^b f(x)dx< \int_a^b g(x)dx \Rightarrow f(x)\leqslant g(x), \forall x \in [a,b]$$ indeed $$\int_0^3 f(x)dx<\int_0^3 g(x)dx$$ but $$\exists x\in[0,3]\text{ such that }f(x)\not\leqslant g(x)\,.$$ Actually, there exists, not just one element $\;x\in[0,3]\;$ such that $\;f(x)\not\leqslant g(x)\,,\text{ but infinite of them, }$ for example any $x\in[0,1[\,.$

Comment: A slightly simpler counterexample (with $f=0$): $0<\int_{-1}^2x\,dx$.